# Sorting a list of lists by length and by value

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
>>> a = [['3D'], ['3D', '4D', '5D'], ['4C'], ['2C'],['4C', '4D'], ['4D'], ['5D'], \
... ['JC'], ['JC', 'JS'], ['JS']]
```

You may notice that this is card values i.e. C= Clubs etc. J = Jack etc. I also have a reference list:

```
>>> confrom = {'3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, \
... '0':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14, '2':15}
```

As I am playing a card game where the maximum value is 2. To sort by length of list, I do:

```
>>> a = sorted(a, key = lambda x: len(x))
>>> a
... [['3D'], ['4C'], ['4D'], ['2C'], ['5D'], ['JC'], ['JS'], ['4C', '4D'], ['JC', 'JS'], ['3D', '4D', '5D']]
```

I need to also sort them according to their dictionary value so my resulting list would be:

```
>>> [['3D'], ['4C'], ['4D'], ['5D'], ['JC'], ['JS'], ['2C'], ['4C', '4D'], ['JC', 'JS'], ['3D', '4D', '5D']]
```

Currently this is quite a simple implementation but I want to be able to sort it in a more complicated way.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
sorted(a, key = lambda x: (len(x), [confrom[card[0]] for card in x]))
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/u9uJz)

Comment: That would work if all the lists were of length 1, but x[0] for a list of ['4C', '4D'] is '4D', so it won;t be able to convert

Answer (score 2):

This may be a really good example of when to transition from a base data structure in Python to a class.

Consider:

```
values = ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A')
suits = ('H', 'C', 'D', 'S')
sRep = {'H':'Hearts', 'C':'Clubs', 'D':'Diamonds', 'S':'Spades'}
ranks = {'2':15, '3':3, '4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,
         '9':9, '0':10, '0':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        value=str(value)
        self.value, self.suit = value.upper(), suit.upper()
        self.rSuit = sRep[suit.upper()]
        self.rank = ranks[value.upper()]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s of %s" % (self.value, self.rSuit)

    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if self.rank > other.rank: return 1
        if self.rank < other.rank: return -1    
        if self.value > other.value: return 1
        if self.value < other.value: return -1
        if self.rSuit > other.rSuit: return 1
        if self.rSuit < other.rSuit: return -1
        return 0
```

Try out some cards:

```
c1=Card(2,'s')     
c2=Card(4,'d')

if c1>c2:
    print "A", c1, "beats a", c2
elif c2>c1:    
    print "A", c2, "beats a", c1
else:
    print "Same..."
```

This prints:

```
A 2 of Spades beats a 4 of Diamonds
```

Since we defined a sort order in the class, complex sorting is easy and ranking based on different games is easy.

Your card list as an example:

```
a = [['3D'], ['3D', '4D', '5D'], ['4C'], ['2C'],['4C', '4D'], ['4D'], ['5D'], ['JC'], ['JC', 'JS'], ['JS']]  

print sorted([Card(c[0],c[1]) for e in a for c in e])
```

Prints:

```
[3 of Diamonds, 3 of Diamonds, 4 of Clubs, 4 of Clubs, 4 of Diamonds, 
 4 of Diamonds, 4 of Diamonds, 5 of Diamonds, 5 of Diamonds, J of Clubs, 
 J of Clubs, J of Spades, J of Spades, 2 of Clubs]
```

With a little more work, you can define hands and what hand beats another hand.

You can read more about this example in the classic Python book How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python [HERE](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch16.html)